# UsbDevice getProductId & getVendorID Android 5.1

Tags: java, android, usb, galaxy

I have an Android app that interacts with USB flash drives. It is filtered to only work with my company's USB drives, and filters them by PID/VID. I get the PID/VID by using the Android [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html) methods getProductId() and getVendorId().

One example combination is PID:1812 VID:7055 (Hex- PID:0714 VID:1B8F)

I have a Galaxy Note 4 device that I am testing with, and it is returning PID:37028 and VID:1748 for a flash drive that has PID:1812 VID:7055.

I've tested on several other mobile devices using the same USB drive, including a few Samsung Galaxy phones. I've never run into this issue before, and I'm at a loss as to why this specific device is returning this value. Can anyone offer any insight here?

--Update--

I have now got the same behavior on a Droid Turbo. Both of these devices are running Android 5.1.1, but it still doesn't explain the wrong PID/VID.

Comment: possibly related Android bugs: [#159529](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159529) [#159897](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159897)

Answer (score 0):

the source code for `getVendorID()` `getProductID()` is in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c6f23e8521dedac7a07119031913235be3ca37c3/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.java it uses native C code (JNI) for getting the data from the kernel module (`usb_storage` for mass storage) or USB host controller

native functions:

```
private native boolean native_open(String deviceName, FileDescriptor pfd);
private native void native_close();
private native int native_get_fd();
private native boolean native_claim_interface(int interfaceID, boolean force);
private native boolean native_release_interface(int interfaceID);
private native int native_control_request(int requestType, int request, int value,
        int index, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout);
private native int native_bulk_request(int endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout);
private native UsbRequest native_request_wait();
private native String native_get_serial();
private static native int native_get_device_id(String name);
private static native String native_get_device_name(int id);
```

maybe this is implemented on the Galaxy Note 4 hardware a bit buggy

if it returns always the **same** VID and PID you only have a small / no problem ...